# Keep getting thrown Error: Username/Password required

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Good afternoon,

Trying to create an SMS booking bot and am running into an issue trying to call the main.js file I have in .src and I'm a bit lost on why.

I have my .env file formatted as needed

```
node src/main.js

>main.js<

require("dotenv").config();

const from = process.env.PHONE_NUMBER
const to = process.env.MY_NUMBER

const twilio = require('twilio')(); 
    process.env.TOKEN_SID,
    process.env.TOKEN_SECRET,
    {
        accountSid: process.env.TOKEN_SID
    }
;

twilio.messages.create({
    from,
    to,
    body: "Hello from Twilio!"
})
.then(message => console.log('Message sent with SID ${message.sid}'))
.catch(error => console.error(error));

>Error output<:

Error: username is required
    at new Twilio (/Users/*/Twilio/sms-booking/backend/node_modules/twilio/lib/rest/Twilio.js:139:11)
    at initializer (/Users/*/Twilio/sms-booking/backend/node_modules/twilio/lib/index.js:10:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/*/Twilio/sms-booking/backend/src/main.js:6:33)

Error: Password is required
    at new Twilio (/Users/*/Twilio/sms-booking/backend/node_modules/twilio/lib/rest/Twilio.js:139:11)
    at initializer (/Users/*/Twilio/sms-booking/backend/node_modules/twilio/lib/index.js:10:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/*/Twilio/sms-booking/backend/src/main.js:6:33)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [twilio error 'username required'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45038260/62576)

Comment: No, not really. I have the SID in the .env in the same format as the person who answered and can confirm it's in the root and the NPM dotenv isn't solving the issue either

Comment: If you log out `process.env.TOKEN_SID` what do you see?

Comment:  I'm so sorry, I thought this had posted. I'm having a bit of trouble getting it to print to the log

Comment: It seems like the issue is  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/el***********r/Twilio/sms-booking/backend/src/main.js:6:33)

Comment: const twilio = require('twilio')(<---